# How can handle this error [PHP]

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day, i'm trying to `save` to my table.

```
function save()
{
    extract(populateform());
    echo "<pre>";print_r(populateform());
    $tipenya = $this->modelmodel->showdata("SELECT * From user_type");
    foreach($tipenya as $types)
    {
        if($pilihan[$types->id_tipe] != ''){    
        foreach($pilihan[$types->id_tipe] as $values){
                echo "insert into tbl a value ('".$values.','.$types->id_tipe."')<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is data that i want to save

```
Array
(
    [pilihan] => Array
        (
            [TP001] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [TP003] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

the result from `print_r($tipenya)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_tipe] => TP001
            [deskripsi] => Developer
            [flag] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_tipe] => TP002
            [deskripsi] => Admin
            [flag] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_tipe] => TP003
            [deskripsi] => Outlet
            [flag] => 1
        )

)
```

and here is the error `Message:  Undefined index: TP002`. But when i try to input this

```
Array
(
    [pilihan] => Array
        (
            [TP001] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [TP002] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [TP003] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

there aren't any error. I'm trying use this but no help

```
if($pilihan[$types->id_tipe] != ''){  }
```

Comment: change `if($pilihan[$types->id_tipe] != '')` to `if(isset($pilihan[$types->id_tipe]) && $pilihan[$types->id_tipe] != '')`

Comment: Perhaps you want `$pilihan['pilihan'][$types->id_tipe]`...? It's a bit unclear what's what here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `isset()` to check if your index is set or not .

`Isset` just checks if is it set, it could be anything not null

```
if(isset($pilihan[$types->id_tipe]) && $pilihan[$types->id_tipe] != ''){
```

**OR**

`Empty` checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc

```
if(!empty($pilihan[$types->id_tipe]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if (isset($pilihan[$types->id_tipe])) {
```